# puppeteer api: only get domain redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, headless-browser, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to get all domain redirects using the Puppeteer api, saved to an array before taking a screenshot of the final URL, but the code I have so far is also getting other redirects.

For example if I `goto youtube.com` then my code will correctly get the redirects `'https://youtube.com/', 'https://www.youtube.com/',`, but it will also get other redirects such as doubleclick.net.

I only want to get the redirects which would happen in the URL bar.

I've managed to narrow it down with `request.resourceType === 'document'`.
How can I narrow it down further??

Here's the code:

```
// node chrome.js http://youtube.com

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var url = process.argv[2];

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, timeout: 30000, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
 // await page.setRequestInterception(true); // hangs with resourcetype

    const urls = [];

    page.on('request', request => {
      // if (request.resourceType === 'document' || request.resourceType === 'script') {
      if (request.resourceType === 'document') { 
      urls.push(request.url);
      request.continue();
      }
    });

    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 20000, waitUntil: 'load'}); //default load

    await page.screenshot({path: 'test.jpg', type: 'jpeg', quality: 80, fullPage: false});
    console.log(urls);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main response is the first response. So you can check it with [once](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener) method of Emitter class:

```
page.once('response', function(response) {
    console.log(`${response.status()} ${response.url()}`); 
});
// page.goto(...);
```

if you want a list of all redirects, you can do:

```
let responses = [];
const _parseMainResponses = function(response) {
    if(response.status() >= 300 && response.status() <= 399) {
        responses.push(response);
    }else {
        responses.push(response);
        // get a non redirect. We can now remove the listener
        page.removeListener('response', _parseMainResponses);
    }
};


// page.goto(...)

responses.map(function(response) {
    console.log(`${response.status()} -> ${response.url()}`);
});
```